# using FORFILES in batch to delete tmp and bak files older than a week

Tags: batch

I am having issues making this syntax work correctly. What I would like to do is remove all tmp and bak files from the specified directory and all subdirectories if the modified date is older than 7 days.

```
for %G in (.tmp, .bak) do forfiles -p "C:\test\cad projects" -s -m *%G -d -7 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

My syntax was gathered from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719347/using-forfiles-with-multiple-file-types-for-search-mask).

If I change my search mask to only include one desired extension then I get correct results.

```
forfiles -p "c:\test\cad projects" -s -m *.bak -d -7 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

I don't do much with batch files so I was hoping someone could assist. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running this from the console, it should work. If you're saving this to a **.bat** file, then the format for variables is a little different. You have to use two percentage signs to signify a variable. So, your command would then become...

```
for %%G in (.tmp, .bak) do forfiles -p "C:\test\cad projects" -s -m *%%G -d -7 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Microsoft's [KB75634](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634) article explains why this is.

> If there are no characters between the two percent signs, one percent sign is stripped off and the other will remain. This is why a FOR command that echos the name of each file with a .COM extension would be
>
> ```
> FOR %V IN (*.COM) DO ECHO %V
> ```
>
> but if the same command is placed in a batch file, the following is required:
>
> ```
> FOR %%V IN (*.COM) DO ECHO %%V
> ```

Comment: @TWood, I added a snippet from Microsoft.com on *why* you have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't read carefully enough on the FOR /R syntax. I was missing a %. My code above would have worked at the command line. From a batch though, it failed because of the missing %.

```
for %%G in (.tmp, .bak) do forfiles -p "C:\test\cad projects" -s -m
*%%G -d -7 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```