# Delete all files and folders in a specific directory older than 1 day except one folder with bat file using forfiles

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I want to delete all folders, subfolders and files older than ome day in a specific directory and leave one folder untouched with the forfiles like the command below:

```
forfiles /p "C:\path\tocheck" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c for /d %%i in (C:\path\tocheck\\*) do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="foldernottobedeleted" rd /s /q "%%i"" /D -1
```

The command above deletes everything except the one file I want to keep included and the files that are new,  it skips the /d parameter.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using PowerShell to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using FORFILES in batch to delete tmp and bak files older than a week](http://superuser.com/questions/650800/using-forfiles-in-batch-to-delete-tmp-and-bak-files-older-than-a-week)